# Symfony2 formbuilder - birthday field - different classes for days, month and years

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony, formbuilder

I have the problem that my Symfony2 form build birthday birthday with bootstrap renders the selects in boxes over the full with.

Is there a posiblity to give days, month and years options on the way to give them different classes in the Twig Template? So I can give them custom widths.

Thanks in Advance. 
Michael

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish that in your template.

For example, I have something like:

```
{{ form_label(form.birthdate) }}
{{ form_widget(form.birthdate.year, { 'attr' : { 'class': 'year-class' }}) }}
{{ form_widget(form.birthdate.month, { 'attr' : { 'class': 'month-class' }}) }}
{{ form_widget(form.birthdate.day, { 'attr' : { 'class': 'day-class' }}) }}
{{ form_errors(form.birthdate) }}
```